# surrogate splitting with Model-based Recursive Partitioning (partykit R)

Tags: r, tree, party

I am estimating a simple `lmtree` model using `partykit` library on R.
In this estimation I have a dependent variable **y**, an explanatory variable **x**, and a set of partitioning variables **z**.

Some of my partitioning variables have a high quantity of missing values, and I noticed that the final estimated model sample size is net of all the missing values in those few categories.
This implies that, as far as at least one of the partitioning variables have a missing value in my data frame, the entire row is removed from the estimation and I lose the information provided by all the rest of **non-missing** partitioning variables.

To solve this problem in more traditional conditional inference trees estimations is used the surrogate splitting (for example, with `ctree_control` function from `partykit` you can select the `maxsurrogate` performed in the `ctree` estimation).

Is it possible to perform surrogate splitting also in `lmtree` (model-based recursive partitioning)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the `partykit` implementation of `mob` (and hence `lmtree` and `glmtree`) does not provide surrogate splits yet.

We are working on a new reimplementation where both `ctree` and `mob` can be used with surrogate variables and both can be used in the background for `lmtree` and `glmtree` etc.

For now the best solution when you need model-based recursive partitioning with surrogate splits is to use `ctree` with a custom model-based `ytrafo` function. This will use the CTree algorithm in the background (rather than MOB) but these often yield rather similar results. From an applied perspective the more important difference is that `lmtree` provides various convenience features, especially for `plot` and `predict`, that `ctree` does not have.